# Where do I find out about Archetypes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype

I keep hearing about "Archetypes" for Pathfinder. What sourcebooks could I read for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Advanced Player's Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8fo1?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Players-Guide)**

> - Variant class abilities, rules subsystems, and thematic archetypes for all 11 core classes, such as the antipaladin, the hungry ghost monk, and the urban ranger.

**[Class Archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes)**

> Archetypes are a quick and easy way to specialize characters of a given class, adding fun and flavorful new abilities to already established adventurers. Characters may take more than one archetype as long as they meet the requirements.

**Using Class Archetypes**

> Each core and base class draws upon a central idea, a basic concept representing the commonly held understanding of what a character of a certain class should be, and is designed to be useful as a foundation to the widest possible array of characters. Beyond that basic concept, however, exists the potential for innumerable interpretations and refinements. A member of the bard class, for example, might be an incorrigible archaeologist, a dashing swashbuckler, or a dangerously graceful dervish dancer, each refined by a player's choice of background details, class options, and specific rules such as feats to better simulate the character she imagines and make that character more effective at pursuing her specific goals.

---

Kobold Press has the [New Paths Compendium](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/products/new-paths-compendium?source_app=shopify-widget&referer=http://mj89sp3sau2k7lj1eg3k40hkeppguj6j-a-sites-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?url=http://www.gstatic.com/sites-gadgets/iframe/iframe.xml&container=enterprise&view=default&lang=en&country=ALL&sanitize=0&v=44d6b25297941457&libs=core&parent=http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes) which has a lot of different archetypes.

---

Some good history of Prestige Class vs. Archetypes can be watched, and read in comments, of [Designer Talk: Prestige Class Problems.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKrwgM_LB5M)

Comment: As a note - I think pretty much every rule book after the Advanced Player's Guide introduced some new Archetypes.

Answer (score 4):

Archetypes were introduced in the Advanced Player's Guide. You can also [read about them on d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes), all the class archetypes are listed at the end of each class page.

Answer (score 2):

In Pathfinder, archetypes are packages of abilities and flavour which can be added on top of base classes. You can add as many archetypes as you meet the requirements for.

A fuller description and links to particular archetypes can be found in the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classArchetypes.html).